# Cannot read property 'next' of undefined using angular 2 Subject

Tags: angular

I implemented bidirectional-service communication as described here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    private authenticatedSource = new Subject<boolean>();
    authenticated$ = this.authenticatedSource.asObservable();

    //..

    login(): void {

        // ...

        return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/signup', user, options)
          .map(this.extractData)
          .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

Inside `extractData` function I call

```
this.authenticatedSource.next(true);
```

but it throws an error:

```
Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
```

When I call `this.authenticatedSource.next(true)` outside of extractData, say inside login function, it works fine. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure that the callback function passed to map() is bound to this:

```
.map(response => this.extractData(response))
```

Comment: Post a complete example, in a plunkr, reproducing the error.